# select one database from a list

Tags: java, jdbc

i am making a program to store data in a database. I have created the code to get connection, to read all the available databases but now i would like to be able to select one specific from the available databases. Could anyone help me how to?
The dode below is the connection with the base and the list of the available databases.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("get the connection");
        }
        catch( Exception e )
         {
         System.out.println( "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() );
         }

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "root");
        DatabaseMetaData meta = (DatabaseMetaData) con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet res = meta.getCatalogs();
        System.out.println("List of the databases: ");
        while (res.next()){
            System.out.println (" " +res.getString(1));
        }
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in);
            System.out.println("Choose a database");
            String theDatabase = keyboard.toString();
            while (theDatabase )
            {
                System.out.println("Enter an existing database");
                theDatabase = keyboard.toString();
            }
            System.out.println("You choose "+theDatabase);
        }
```

How i have to continue?? I want to continue the rest program with the selected database.
What i have to write in while(theDatabase) ???

Comment: If you have found `DatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs()`, why haven't you tried the logical method [`Connection.setCatalog(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String))

Comment: How i would do it with this?

Comment: How about passing the name of the catalog (database in MySQL terms) to `setCatalog(...)`

Answer (score 3):

create multiple connection objects each one for each database like

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "root");

Connection con1 = Create connection using oracle


if(theDatabase.equals("mysql"))
//use con
else 
//use con2
```

or

```
 Connection con = null;

 if(theDatabase.equals("mysql"))
      con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "root");
else 
       con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(oracle);
```

Then use

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+theDatabase, "root", "root");
```

Comment: no, what i mean is that i have plenty of database in mysql. After i list their names i would like to select one of them!

Comment: What  you are going to do with while here

Comment: I want to be sure that the selected database is in the list, if not loop is entered if input is invalid. If the selected database is in the list use this!

Comment: Then try to put all avialable lists in a Arraylist then check

Comment: do you mention database names in the application

Answer (score 1):

you can prefix the table-name with database-name. for example if the database name is DB1 and table name is TB1, then your query could be

select * from DB1.TB1

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the database which is selected.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+theDatabase, "root", "root");

// Do your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

to select your database add your Dababasename here :

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName", "root", "root");
```

Comment: I don't want to give it here!I would like first to list all the available and afterwrds to select the one!